# How to iterate a dynamic GET response

Tags: c#

How can i iterate a GET response if i dont know the structure i will get in advance. 
Lets say i can get this response:

```
{
    "hostName": "host",
    "domainName": "domain",
}
```

and the next time i send the same GET request i get this response:

```
{
    "hostName": "host",
}
```

my code so far:

```
public static void GetRequest(string url)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    String userId = "userID";
    String userPassword = "userPassword";
    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userId, userPassword);
    httpWebRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;
    httpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 3;
    httpWebRequest.Timeout = 5000;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
    string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userId + ":" + userPassword));
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
    Console.WriteLine("Sending HTTP Request");
    var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    if (responseStream != null)
    {
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP Response is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    if (responseStream != null) responseStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Convert to anonymous object using JSON#Convert and then iterate over the properties.

Comment: Look into [JSON.Net's `JObject.Parse`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm)

Comment: Do you really need to iterate? Isn't better to create single object with all possible properties you can get and just left them null in case those are not present in the response? This you can manage just with JsonConvert<MyResponseType> and some settings.

Comment: cloudikka, can you show an example?